# SVG path element is not triggering mouse events in JavaFX8 webview

Tags: javascript, svg, webview, webkit, javafx-8

I have a html page with inline SVG. and there is a event handler on path element.
This works perfectly in browsers (Chrome/IE/FF) but when i try this in a webview of JAVAFX8.
click event is not triggered for path element.

here is the sample code.

    http://jsfiddle.net/YTWw9/4/

```
    $('path').click(function(event){
        $(event.target).attr('stroke', "yellow");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used different method using SVG and XML with database links and it is posted in my blogspot

http://mksugumaran.blogspot.in/2014/04/svg-scalable-vector-graphics-in-web-page.html

The source code used is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tamilnadu Rainfall data in GIS</title>
<style>
p.pos_fixed1
{
FONT: bold 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
COLOR: #000066;
position:fixed;
top:30px;
left:20px;
z-index=10;
}
p.pos_fixed2
{
FONT: bold 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
COLOR: #000066;
position:fixed;
top:45px;
left:20px;
z-index=10;
}
iframe.pos_fixed3
{
top:75px;
left:0px;
position:fixed;
width:250px;
height:300px;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript">
var aHexArray="0123456789ABCDEF";
var LLXC=75.0;
var LUYC=13.5833332538605;
var CS=0.00083333333333333;
var x1 = new Array();
var y1 = new Array();
var n1,ild;
var i,j;
var nx;
function fnRandomDec(){
var iMaxDec=256;
var iRandDec=parseInt((iMaxDec*Math.random())-1);
return iRandDec;
}
function fnReturnHex(iDecValue){
return aHexArray.charAt((iDecValue>>4)&0xf)+aHexArray.charAt(iDecValue&0xf);
}
function fnRandColor(){
return "#" + fnReturnHex(fnRandomDec()) + fnReturnHex(fnRandomDec()) + fnReturnHex(fnRandomDec());
}

function drawing(zx)
{
var txt1;
txt1=""
y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].childNodes;
//document.write(y.length-1);
//document.write("<svg onclick=fnchange(); width='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "' height='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "'>");

txt1= txt1 + "<svg style=z-index:2; width='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "' height='" + Math.round(6700/zx) + "' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>";
for (j=0;j<y.length;j++)
{
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Polygon")[j].childNodes;
//document.write(x.length-1);
//document.write("<polygon points='");
name=x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
txt1=txt1 + "<a xlink:title=" + name + " xlink:href='wdb4x.asp?dbname=tnrfs&2=xx'" + " target='xy1'>"
txt1= txt1 + "<polygon points='";
for (i=1;i<x.length;i++)
{
  gxy=x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  n1=gxy.indexOf(",");
  x1[i]=gxy.substr(0,n1);
  y1[i]=gxy.substr(n1+1);
  txt1= txt1 +Math.round(x1[i]/zx)+','+Math.round(y1[i]/zx)+' '
}

txt1=txt1 +"' style='fill:" + fnRandColor() + ";stroke:black;stroke-width:1'></polygon></a>";
}
colr=fnRandColor();
y=xmlDoc1.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].childNodes;
for (j=0;j<y.length;j++)
{
x=xmlDoc1.getElementsByTagName("point")[j].childNodes;
name=x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
gxy=x[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
n1=gxy.indexOf(",");
xx1=gxy.substr(0,n1);
yy1=gxy.substr(n1+1);
str1=name + ':' + Math.abs(LUYC-yy1*CS) + ',' + Math.abs(LLXC+xx1*CS);
txt1=txt1 + "<a xlink:title=" + str1 + " xlink:href='wdb4x.asp?dbname=tnrfs&2=" + name + "' target='xy1'"+"'>";

txt1=txt1 + "<circle cx='" + Math.round(xx1/zx) +"' cy='" + Math.round(yy1/zx) + "' r='5' stroke='black' stroke-width='1' fill='"+ fnRandColor() +"'></circle></a>";
}
txt1=txt1 + "</svg>";
scr1.innerHTML=txt1;
}
function position3(xx1,yy1)
{
xy1.style.top=Math.round(yy1/zx);
xy1.style.left=Math.round(xx1/zx);
}
function fnchange()
{
nx=nx-1;
if(nx==0)nx=1;
drawing(nx);
}
function fnchange1()
{
nx=nx+1;
if(nx>10)nx=10;
drawing(nx);
}

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
function loadXMLString(txt)
{
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
  }
return xmlDoc;
}
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("tnbasins.xml");
xmlDoc1=loadXMLDoc("tnrfl.xml");

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class="pos_fixed1" onclick="fnchange1();">zoom_out</p>
<p class="pos_fixed2" onclick="fnchange();">zoom_in</p>
<iframe class="pos_fixed3" style=width:250;height:300;z-index:1; z-index=-1; name=xy1 border=none frameborder=none></iframe>
<table><tr><td id=scr1></td></tr></table>
<script language="javascript">
if (xmlDoc && xmlDoc1)
{
nx=10;
drawing(nx);
}
</SCRIPT>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are enclosing the polygon element by anchor tag and therefore enabling the clicks. but my question is bit different, I wanted to know why the mouse events are not triggered from path elements \(events are triggered from other elements like text) in web view.